# Emoji sizing issues with custom font in uitextfield or uiwebview

Tags: ios, fonts, uiwebview, emoji

I'm developing an app on iOS and I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to make an "editable text" where the user could change the color,the size and the font.

It's working great with `UITextField`, but when the user add "emoji emoticon" the emoticons appear to be shrunk. I Know that this is a common problem, and could be fixed by setting the font to "AppleColorEmoji".But I really love to be able to let the user pick a font and still be able to add emoticons.

I need a way to add two fonts in one editable text, one for displaying emoji with "appleColorEmoji" for big scale and custom font for classic characters.

I tried to do it with `UIWebView`, but I really don't know how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.